# How to insert a collapsible into a flexbox layout

Tags: css

I have a flexbox layout of images wraping on rows and I want to display some information when an image is clicked. This information shall be displayed between the line containing the image and the line just under it, without moving the "columns".
This is the type of effect I want: http://olmenta.altervista.org (when you click on a book).

Here is what I have done: https://jsfiddle.net/fabhpnw9/3/

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The "columns" are shifting because the size of the flex-item changes.
I can fix this by adding "position: absolute" to the text but then the text collides with the following line.
Do you see how I can have both the columns not moving and the text not colliding with the following line?

Comment: The example site you provided doesn't use `flexbox`. Do you need to use `flexbox`?

Comment: @HK No I don't need to use flexbox, I just thought it was good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we switch to toggling the `active` class on the `.flex-item`, we can add a height to the active `.flex-item` to allow space for the `.text`.

Note: In order to position the `.text` element correctly, it is important that the `.flex-item`s are not positioned (or `position: static`). Otherwise the `left: 0` of the `.text` will be at the left of the parent `.flex-item`.

Here is a snippet of a working example:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.flex-item.active').forEach(x => x.classList.remove('active'))
    this.parentElement.classList.add("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 200px;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-item.active {
  height: 155px;
}

.flex-item:not(.active) .text {
  display: none;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*tooltip styles*/
.flex-item.active .rectangle::after {
  content: '';
  border: solid 10px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 10px grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[The Details disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) already has an *open/close* mechanism built into the browser. So why not use that and modify its behavior to meet our requirements.

The basic principle would be

```html
<details>
   <summary>some clickable content</summary>
   <div>
      Any content you want to disclose when the <summary> gets clicked
   </div>
</details>
```

- With CSS we can control how and where the content is displayed. Whether we use the default block styling, or Flexbox/Grid layout, position content outside the regular document flow or not. They are regular elements, so essentially anything goes.
- As, by default, `detail/summary` stay open when a user clicks elsewhere, We need some Javascript to *auto close* currently 'disclosed' content.
- Users tend to get confused when they don't see a 'closing button', so I put one in there. But, clicking anywhere in the *information box* will close it.

I went a bit overboard with this and created a responsive demo, completely ignoring your code (sorry!) while trying to stay as close to the example site as possible. I commented everything where applicable. Let me know in the comments if things are unclear.

**snippet**

```js
// Contains a reference to the current 'open' <details> element
var currentDetail;

// Walk the list of all grid cells => <details>
document.querySelectorAll('.grid .cell').forEach(el => {

    // Walk the list of grid cell children and attach eventlisteners
    for (const child of el.children) {

        // When it's a preview, toggle its information box
        // or open another when the information box is already visible.
        if (child.classList.contains('preview')) {
            // this event triggers before <details> 'toggle' event
            child.addEventListener("click", event => { toggleDetails(event.currentTarget.closest('.cell')) });
            // Finds closest parent .cell
        }

        // When it is an information box, just close it.
        if (child.classList.contains('information')) {
            child.addEventListener("click", event => { closeDetails() });
        }
    };
});

function toggleDetails(el) {
    if (el.open) { /* Browser is about to trigger details 'toggle' */
        currentDetail = null; // all details closed
    }
    else { // not null and different detail
        if ((currentDetail) && (currentDetail != el)) {

            currentDetail.removeAttribute('open'); // close current open detail
        };
        currentDetail = el; // save new opened detail
    };
};

function closeDetails() {
    if (currentDetail) { // Details open?
        currentDetail.removeAttribute('open'); // close current open detail
        currentDetail = null;                  // all details closed
    };
};
```

```css
/* * { outline: 1px dashed } /* for debugging */

/********************************/
/* some convenient global rules */
/********************************/
*, ::before, ::after { box-sizing: border-box }
/* makes padding and border part of any element total size, margin never */

html, body  { width: 100%; max-width: 100% }
html        { scroll-behavior: smooth }

body {
    margin: unset; /* Kill default margin */

    min-height: 100vh;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 1rem;

    overscroll-behavior: contain; /* Check MDN for this */
}

details, /* Remove CSS defaults */
summary { padding: 0; list-style: none }

img {
    display: block;        /* removes little whitespace below image */
    width: 100%;           /* stretch to full width */
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1.5; /* or height: auto, your choice */
    object-fit: cover;     /* fill parent, but clip when it doesn't fit */
}

/* Responsive font sizing */
/* Using linear equation y=mx+b => y=0.00625x + 12 (320,14)(1280,20) */
html { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) }
body { font-size: 1rem }

/************************************/
/* DEMO, base layout - mobile first */
/************************************/
.grid {
    display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.cell {
    /* fiddle with these properties */
    flex-grow: 1;                /* [OPTIONAL] */
    min-width: min(12rem, 100%); /* set to desired width */

    cursor: pointer;
}

.cell .preview { border: 1px solid Black }

.cell .information {
    overflow: auto; overscroll-behavior: contain;

    position: fixed;    /* within viewport */
    z-index: 99999;     /* over any body content */
    inset: 0%;          /* full screen */

    gap: 1rem;
    padding: 4rem 1rem 1rem;

    background-color: hsl(0,0%,14%); color: hsl(0,0%,90%);

    cursor: default;
}

/****************************/
/* Some responsive behavior */
/****************************/
@media all and (min-width: 361px) {
    .cell .information {
        display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content: center;

        inset: 30% 0% 0%;   /* stay % from sides */
        padding: 4rem;
        opacity: 0.985;
    }

    .cell .information img {
        width: auto; max-width: min(360px, 100%);
    }
}
/* Dito */
@media all and (min-width: 721px) {
    .cell {
        flex-grow: 0; /* [OPTIONAL] */
    }
}
/* Allow content to grow, only relevant on +360px devices */
/* as <361px are has no flexbox parent */
.cell .information > * { flex: 1 }

/**********************************************/
/* The .information 'x' close button behavior */
/**********************************************/
.cell .information .close {
    position: absolute; top: 0.75rem; right: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 2em; font-style: normal;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.cell .information .close::after       { content: "\2715" }
.cell .information .close:hover::after { content: "\2716" }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <details class="cell">
        <summary class="preview"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=1"></summary>
        <div class="information">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=1">
            <div class="text">
                <h3  class="title">Nice Description</h3>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pri eirmod dolores ponderum. Per ea case posse libris, eros magna ius no. Rebum dicat legere sit ut. Mentitum consequat eam et. Omnis quaeque blandit mei in. Ius debet vulputate ut.
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="close" role="img" aria-label="Close"></i>
        </div>
    </details>
 
    <details class="cell">
        <summary class="preview"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=2"></summary>
        <div class="information">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=2">
            <div class="text">
                <h3  class="title">Nice Description</h3>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pri eirmod dolores ponderum. Per ea case posse libris, eros magna ius no. Rebum dicat legere sit ut. Mentitum consequat eam et. Omnis quaeque blandit mei in. Ius debet vulputate ut.
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="close" role="img" aria-label="Close"></i>
        </div>
    </details>
 
    <details class="cell">
        <summary class="preview"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=3"></summary>
        <div class="information">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=3">
            <div class="text">
                <h3  class="title">Nice Description</h3>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pri eirmod dolores ponderum. Per ea case posse libris, eros magna ius no. Rebum dicat legere sit ut. Mentitum consequat eam et. Omnis quaeque blandit mei in. Ius debet vulputate ut.
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="close" role="img" aria-label="Close"></i>
        </div>
    </details>
 
    <details class="cell">
        <summary class="preview"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=4"></summary>
        <div class="information">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=4">
            <div class="text">
                <h3  class="title">Nice Description</h3>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pri eirmod dolores ponderum. Per ea case posse libris, eros magna ius no. Rebum dicat legere sit ut. Mentitum consequat eam et. Omnis quaeque blandit mei in. Ius debet vulputate ut.
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="close" role="img" aria-label="Close"></i>
        </div>
    </details>
 
    <details class="cell">
        <summary class="preview"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=5"></summary>
        <div class="information">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=5">
            <div class="text">
                <h3  class="title">Nice Description</h3>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pri eirmod dolores ponderum. Per ea case posse libris, eros magna ius no. Rebum dicat legere sit ut. Mentitum consequat eam et. Omnis quaeque blandit mei in. Ius debet vulputate ut.
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="close" role="img" aria-label="Close"></i>
        </div>
    </details>
 
    <details class="cell">
        <summary class="preview"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=6"></summary>
        <div class="information">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=6">
            <div class="text">
                <h3  class="title">Nice Description</h3>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pri eirmod dolores ponderum. Per ea case posse libris, eros magna ius no. Rebum dicat legere sit ut. Mentitum consequat eam et. Omnis quaeque blandit mei in. Ius debet vulputate ut.
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="close" role="img" aria-label="Close"></i>
        </div>
    </details>
 
    <details class="cell">
        <summary class="preview"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=7"></summary>
        <div class="information">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=7">
            <div class="text">
                <h3  class="title">Nice Description</h3>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pri eirmod dolores ponderum. Per ea case posse libris, eros magna ius no. Rebum dicat legere sit ut. Mentitum consequat eam et. Omnis quaeque blandit mei in. Ius debet vulputate ut.
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="close" role="img" aria-label="Close"></i>
        </div>
    </details>
 
    <details class="cell">
        <summary class="preview"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=8"></summary>
        <div class="information">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=8">
            <div class="text">
                <h3  class="title">Nice Description</h3>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pri eirmod dolores ponderum. Per ea case posse libris, eros magna ius no. Rebum dicat legere sit ut. Mentitum consequat eam et. Omnis quaeque blandit mei in. Ius debet vulputate ut.
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="close" role="img" aria-label="Close"></i>
        </div>
    </details>
 
    <details class="cell">
        <summary class="preview"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=9"></summary>
        <div class="information">
            <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/150/225?random=9">
            <div class="text">
                <h3  class="title">Nice Description</h3>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id pri eirmod dolores ponderum. Per ea case posse libris, eros magna ius no. Rebum dicat legere sit ut. Mentitum consequat eam et. Omnis quaeque blandit mei in. Ius debet vulputate ut.
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="close" role="img" aria-label="Close"></i>
        </div>
    </details>
</div>
```

Comment: Also a big thank you for your answer, I didn't know about the details disclosure element, and I'll use your CSS to style my collapsible!